# writing test for importing contents of text file into database using python and django

Tags: python, django, automated-tests

I have to import some text files into a MySQL database. These are basically just TSV files, and each row represents an instance of a Django model. I'm new to writing tests and I'm not really sure what I need to test for in a task like this. In some cases, a row in a text file corresponds to an insert statement, sometimes it's an update.

Say my model looks like this:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field4 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field5 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field6 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field7 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field8 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field9 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field10 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

After calling the method for importing, should I just test whether an object with fields equal to those of the object from the text file exists in the database? Something like this:

```
def test_parts_dump():

    parts = importer.dump_parts() # parts is a list of Part objects imported from a text file

        for part in parts:

            part_exists = Part.objects.filter(
                pk=part.pk,
                field1=part.field1,
                field2=part.field2,
                field3=part.field3,
                field4=part.field4,
                field5=part.field5,
                field6=part.field6,
                field7=part.field7,
                field8=part.field8,
                field9=part.field9,
                field10=part.field10)
                .exists()
            self.assertTrue(part_exists)
```

As I said previously, sometimes the imported rows are updates to existing rows so I can't just check if an object with the same pk exists. Is this how I should go about testing this at all? And if it is, is there an easier way to check if an identical object exists in the database without having to specify all of its fields?

Comment: Django doesn't support composite keys, so if you can't check for object uniqueness by primary key, I'm not sure what's going to work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd go with this:

```
fieldnames = [ 'field%s' % (i, ) for i in range(1, 11) ]
for part in parts:
     existing_part = Part.objects.get(pk=part.pk)
     for fn in fieldnames:
          self.assertEqual(getattr(existing_part, fn),
                           getattr(part,          fn),
                           "Problem in part %s field %s" % (part.pk, fn))
```

Makes it easier to understand the problem when you encounter it.

If you want to validate all fields of a Django model, you can replace the first line (`fieldnames = ...`) with:

```
fields = [ f.name for f in Part._meta.fields if f.name != 'id' ]
```